# How do I echo stars (*) when reading password with `read`?

Tags: bash, shell, passwords

What do I need to do for code in Bash, if I want to echo `*`s in place of password characters (or even just hide the characters completely) when the user types something in using `read`?

Comment: If you're within the systemd ecosystem, you can use systemd-ask-password: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-ask-password.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As **Mark Rushakoff** pointed out, `read -s` will suppress the echoing of characters typed at the prompt. You can make use of that feature as part of this script to echo asterisks for each character typed:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset password
prompt="Enter Password:"
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    prompt='*'
    password+="$char"
done
echo
echo "Done. Password=$password"
```

Comment: You need to `unset IFS` or add `IFS=` to your while loop otherwise your loop will prematurely break on passwords that contain spaces.  Also, you should add the `-r` flag to `read` so that passwords can contain backslashes.

Comment: `password+="$char"` didn't work on my system. I had to do `password="${password}${char}"` instead.

Comment: @BradMace: You must not be using Bash, ksh (93) or zsh or you are using a very old version of Bash (e.g. 2.05b).

Answer (score 30):

I really liked the answer that **Wirone** gave, but I didn't like that the backspacing would continue removing characters even back into the "Enter password: " prompt.

I also had some issues where pressing keys too rapidly would cause some of the characters to actually print on the screen... never a good thing when prompting for a password.  =)

The following is my modified version of **Wirone**'s answer which addresses these issues:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset PASSWORD
unset CHARCOUNT

echo -n "Enter password: "

stty -echo

CHARCOUNT=0
while IFS= read -p "$PROMPT" -r -s -n 1 CHAR
do
    # Enter - accept password
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\0' ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    # Backspace
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\177' ]] ; then
        if [ $CHARCOUNT -gt 0 ] ; then
            CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT-1))
            PROMPT=$'\b \b'
            PASSWORD="${PASSWORD%?}"
        else
            PROMPT=''
        fi
    else
        CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT+1))
        PROMPT='*'
        PASSWORD+="$CHAR"
    fi
done

stty echo

echo $PASSWORD
```

Comment: A more advance version is [ask_password_stars](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/software/#ask_password_stars).  It was developed as part of my personal notes on [Cryptogrphy, Password Input](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/crypto/passwd_input.txt).

Comment: I like this answer. I inserted an `echo` before the `break`.

Answer (score 14):

`read -s` should put it in silent mode:

```
-s     Silent mode.  If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed.
```

See the `read` section in [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: He wants some feedback, not noecho silence!

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add something to **Dennis Williamson**'s solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset password
echo -n "Enter password: "
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    # Enter - accept password
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    # Backspace
    if [[ $char == $'\177' ]] ; then
        prompt=$'\b \b'
        password="${password%?}"
    else
        prompt='*'
        password+="$char"
    fi
done
```

In above example script handles backspace correctly.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/299469)

Comment: It handles DEL "correctly". It doesn't do anything special with backspace (Ctrl-H).

Comment: "_Normal_" users rather use standard backspace, not Ctrl+H. Above script does not handle correctly arrow keys too, but hey, it's better to handle backspace and _not_ handle Ctrl+H, or don't handle both? ;)

Comment: Ctrl-H *is* backspace (the Unicode standard calls it `BACKSPACE`). `$'\177'` is DEL (Unicode calls it `DELETE`). Some terminal programs may optionally map the Backspace key to the DEL character, but many "*normal*" users, including myself, map it to the backspace (Ctrl-H) character. A robust solution would examine the user's tty settings.

Comment: I didn't mean Unicode. I said only that for standard user backspace is a key on the keyboard, with "backspace" label ;) And this is what is mapped in script.

Comment: What I wrote applies to Unicode, ASCII, and Latin-N for various values of N. `$'\177'` is the `DEL` character; the backspace character is `$'\010'` or `'\b'`. What "standard" are you referring to? (When I type Ctrl-V Backspace at a shell prompt, it echoes `^H`; am I violating some standard?)

Comment: Dude, I just refer to `keyboard layout`. I didn't see `$'\177'`, `$'\010'` nor `'\b'` on any button. I didn't mean any standards like ASCII. Backspace is considered to delete char before caret, `DEL` - after it, user does not have to know what char/code it sends. EOT.

Comment: Dude, the backspace key on *my* keyboard sends an ASCII BS character (8), *not* an ASCII DEL character (127). My tty settings are such that typing backspace deletes the character before the cursor. It's configurable, and your code assumes a particular configuration that is not universal. There is nothing non-standard or abnormal about my setup, and your code would not work properly with it.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the character for the backspace, add `backspace=$(tput kbs)` before entering the loop and then compare $char against $backspace. That way it'll work no matter what value the user has set their backspace key to send.

Comment: Thanks for `tput`, but to be 100% sure it's working we need to know if user has `tput` in path, which is not obvious (I didn't have, because I'm using Cygwin and had to install `ncurses` to get it). Will try to implement it meanwhile ;)

Comment: A more advance version is [ask_password_stars](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/software/#ask_password_stars).  It was developed as part of my personal notes on [Cryptogrphy, Password Input](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/crypto/passwd_input.txt).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about stars, but stty -echo is your friend:

```
 #!/bin/sh 
 read -p "Username: " uname 
 stty -echo 
 read -p "Password: " passw; echo 
 stty echo
```

Source: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/passwords-with-bash

Comment: That hardly seems necessary since `read` has a `-s` option (the question is tagged `bash` so we can assume bash-specific features). Interrupting the `read` command (e.g., by typing control-C) could leave the tty in `-echo` mode.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about it being interactive, you can simply do

```
read -s pass
echo "$pass" | sed 's/./*/g'
```

This will show a * for each character of the entered password after enter is pressed.

Comment: This just makes your application look buggy

Answer (score 3):

```
stty -echo
read something
stty echo
```

will stop user input being echoed to the screen for that read. Depending on what you are doing with prompts, you may want to add an extra `echo` command to generate a newline after the read.

Answer (score 3):

[@nxnev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9086893/nxnev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110072/2585092) didn't *quite* work for me, at least on macOS. I simplified it a bit, and now it's flawless:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ask() {
    charcount='0'
    prompt="${1}: "
    reply=''
    while IFS='' read -n '1' -p "${prompt}" -r -s 'char'
    do
        case "${char}" in
            # Handles NULL
            ( $'\000' )
            break
            ;;
            # Handles BACKSPACE and DELETE
            ( $'\010' | $'\177' )
            if (( charcount > 0 )); then
                prompt=$'\b \b'
                reply="${reply%?}"
                (( charcount-- ))
            else
                prompt=''
            fi
            ;;
            ( * )
            prompt='*'
            reply+="${char}"
            (( charcount++ ))
            ;;
        esac
    done
    printf '\n' >&2
    printf '%s\n' "${reply}"
}

pwd="$(ask Password)"

echo "Your password is $pwd"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just made this Bash-specific function based on **Dennis Williamson**'s, **Wirone**'s and **Logan VanCuren**'s answers:

```
ask() {
  local 'args' 'char' 'charcount' 'prompt' 'reply' 'silent'

  # Basic arguments parsing
  while [[ "${1++}" ]]; do
    case "${1}" in
      ( '--silent' | '-s' )
        silent='yes'
        ;;
      ( '--' )
        args+=( "${@:2}" )
        break
        ;;
      ( * )
        args+=( "${1}" )
        ;;
    esac
    shift || break
  done

  if [[ "${silent}" == 'yes' ]]; then
    for prompt in "${args[@]}"; do
      charcount='0'
      prompt="${prompt}: "
      reply=''
      while IFS='' read -n '1' -p "${prompt}" -r -s 'char'; do
        case "${char}" in
          # Handles NULL
          ( $'\000' )
            break
            ;;
          # Handles BACKSPACE and DELETE
          ( $'\010' | $'\177' )
            if (( charcount > 0 )); then
              prompt=$'\b \b'
              reply="${reply%?}"
              (( charcount-- ))
            else
              prompt=''
            fi
            ;;
          ( * )
            prompt='*'
            reply+="${char}"
            (( charcount++ ))
            ;;
        esac
      done
      printf '\n' >&2
      printf '%s\n' "${reply}"
    done
  else
    for prompt in "${args[@]}"; do
      IFS='' read -p "${prompt}: " -r 'reply'
      printf '%s\n' "${reply}"
    done
  fi
}
```

It could be used like:

```
$ ask Username
Username: AzureDiamond
AzureDiamond

$ ask -s Password
Password: *******
hunter2

$ ask First Second Third
First: foo
foo
Second: bar
bar
Third: baz
baz
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "------------------------------"

n=7
echo " Enter Password :"

for (( i=1;i<n;i++ ))
do
    stty -echo
    read -r -s -n 1 char
    stty echo

    echo -n "*"
    pass+="$char"

done

echo " "
echo " Your password : $pass "

echo ""
echo "-------------------------------"
```

Comment: I'm far from beeing a bash-expert, but I think this code has several issues (like password having a fixed length of 6 and not working with backspaces)