# How do I make a TUI dialog box?

Tags: c, linux, bash, tui

Is there a way to replicate this: [TUI dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRZR1.png)(screenshot not mine of course) on something Shell Script or something like C? This looks better than using [dialog](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dialog.1.html) package.

Comment: you might want `whiptail`

Comment: This is essentially a tool recommendation question (a category which is as a whole off-topic here); every reasonable answer will involve `dialog` or one of its many competitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically every programming language allows you to make TUI or CLI.

#### Reproducing what you want to achieve

Probably, the most dumb way to implement that is to use ANSI escape codes and UNICODE characters. You can draw a colored menu and move the cursor to override the output or to hide the useless stuff.
Example using bare bash: [link to GitHub Gist - password_input_tui.sh](https://gist.github.com/mikyll/225eb3e72afa139bca71306e58f53061)

```
#!/bin/bash

max_pass_length=40
pass_length=30
i=0
password=
prompt=$'     \u2502 Passphrase: '

clear
echo -e "\e[32;40m\e[H"

echo -e "     \u250C\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2510     "
echo -e "     \u2502 Please enter the passphrase to                       \u2502     "
echo -e "     \u2502 protect your new key                                 \u2502     "
echo -e "     \u2502                                                      \u2502     "
echo -e -n "     \u2502 Passphrase: "; while [ $i -lt $pass_length ]; do echo -e -n "_"; i=$(expr $i + 1); done; while [ $i -lt $max_pass_length ]; do echo -e -n " "; i=$(expr $i + 1); done; echo -e " \u2502     "
echo -e "     \u2502                                                      \u2502     "
echo -e "     \u2502       <OK>                              <Cancel>     \u2502     "
echo -e "     \u2514\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2518     "


echo -e "\e[5;H"

# Read password

i=0
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    if [[ $i -eq $(expr $pass_length - 1) ]]
    then
        password+=$'\0'
        break
    fi
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    if [[ $char == $'\177' || $char == $'\b' ]]
    then
        if [ $i -gt 0 ]
        then
            i=$(expr $i - 1)
            prompt=$'\b_\b'
            password="${password%?}"
        else
            prompt=''
        fi
    else
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
        prompt='*'
        password+="$char"
    fi
done

# Select <OK> or <Cancel>

choice=1

echo -e -n "\e[8;14H\e[30;42m<OK>\e[0m\e[10H"
while read -r -s -n 1 ui; do
    case "$ui" in
    $'\x1b')    # Handle ESC sequence.
        # Flush read. We account for sequences for Fx keys as
        # well. 6 should suffice far more then enough.
        read -r -s -n 1 -t 0.1 char
        if [[ "$char" == "[" ]]; then
            read -r -s -n 1 -t 0.1 char
            case "$char" in
            #"A") printf "Up\n";;
            #"B") printf "Down\n";;
            "C") # right
                echo -e -n "\e[8;14H\e[32;40m<OK>\e[0m" 
                echo -e -n "\e[8;48H\e[30;42m<Cancel>\e[0m"
                echo -e -n "\e[10H"
                choice=0;;
            "D") # left
                echo -e -n "\e[8;14H\e[30;42m<OK>\e[0m" 
                echo -e -n "\e[8;48H\e[32;40m<Cancel>\e[0m"
                echo -e -n "\e[10H"
                choice=1;;
            esac
        fi
        # Flush "stdin" with 0.1  sec timeout.
        read -rsn5 -t 0.1
        ;;
    $'\0')
        break ;;     
    # Other one byte (char) cases. Here only quit.
    q)
        choice=1
        break;;
    esac
done

# Show result

if [[ choice -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "Password: $password"
else
    echo "Operation canceled"
fi

exit 0
```

Output: [bash.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8eLN.gif)

References:

- [ANSI color codes](https://www.shellhacks.com/bash-colors/)
- [Mask password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24600839/19544859)
- [Read arrows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179193)

But that example has many problems and bits that could be improved (for example this code doesn't validate the password characters, and special characters like CTRL+stuff are considered as 2+ characters) and it's probably much harder than using tools made exactly for this task (e.g. dialog).

Another example (C++) using curses: [Link to GitHub Gist - password_input_tui.cpp](https://gist.github.com/mikyll/3874111593da128a073d295d33ee2dd1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curses.h>

#define MAX_PASSWD_LENGTH 32
#define M1Y     7
#define M1X     8
#define M2Y     7
#define M2X     33

void menu(int choice);

int yBottom, xBottom;
int yTop, xTop;
WINDOW* win;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    initscr();
    
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    
    
    int xMax, yMax, i, choice, exit;
    char password[MAX_PASSWD_LENGTH];
    char ch;
    
    getmaxyx(stdscr, yMax, xMax);
    yBottom = yMax / 1.5, xBottom = xMax / 1.5;
    yTop = yMax / 6, xTop = xMax / 6;
    win = newwin(yBottom, xBottom, yTop, xTop);
    
    
    box(win, 0, 0);
    
    mvwprintw(win, 2, 2, "Please enter the passphrase to");
    mvwprintw(win, 3, 2, "protect your new key");
    mvwprintw(win, 5, 2, "Passphrase: ");
    
    i=0;
    while (i < MAX_PASSWD_LENGTH) {
        ch = wgetch(win);
        
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == 27 || ch == 127) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == '\b' || ch == 8) {
            if (i > 0) {
                mvwprintw(win, 5, 14 + i, "\b \b");
                --i;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == 10 || ch == '\r' || ch == '\t') {
            break;
        }
        else if (ch == 0 || ch == 224) {
            ch = wgetch(win);
            continue;
        }
        else {
            mvwprintw(win, 5, 14 + i, "*");
            password[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
    password[i] = '\0';
    
    wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
    mvwprintw(win, M1Y, M1X, "<OK>");
    wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
    mvwprintw(win, M2Y, M2X, "<Cancel>");
    
    choice = 1;
    exit = 0;
    while(ch = wgetch(win))
    {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '\033':
            {
                wgetch(win);
                switch(wgetch(win))
                {
                    case 'D':
                    {
                        choice = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'C':
                    {
                        choice = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case '\n':
            {
                exit = 1;
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        if(exit)
            break;
        menu(choice);
    }
    
    if(choice == 1)
        mvwprintw(win, 10, 10, "Password: %s", password);
    else
        mvwprintw(win, 10, 10, "Operation canceled");
    wgetch(win);
    
    endwin();
    
    return 0;
}

void menu(int choice)
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
            mvwprintw(win, M1Y, M1X, "<OK>");
            wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
            mvwprintw(win, M2Y, M2X, "<Cancel>");
            break;
        case 2:
            mvwprintw(win, M1Y, M1X, "<OK>");
            wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
            mvwprintw(win, M2Y, M2X, "<Cancel>");
            wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
            break;
        default:
            wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
            mvwprintw(win, M1Y, M1X, "<OK>");
            wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
            mvwprintw(win, M2Y, M2X, "<Cancel>");
            break;
    }
}
```

Output: [cpp.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba2hl.gif)

To make this work (as per dialog) obviously you have to make sure you have installed curses (Example for Debian: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`, and use `-lncurses` flag when you compile it with g++).

#### Some C Code for Windows

I suggest you take a look at [TurboVision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision), which is a TUI framework released for MS-DOS in 1990. There's a interesting [modern port on GitHub](https://github.com/magiblot/tvision), which is cross platform. Here's a bit of what you can do: [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOtM3.png).

Otherwise you could include `windows.h` header and use `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` to **color the output**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hConsole;
    int k;

    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // you can loop k higher to see more color choices
    for (k = 1; k < 255; k++)
    {
        // pick the colorattribute k you want
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, k);
        printf("%3d  %s\n", k, "I want to be nice today!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O99IP.png)

Or simply handle the input stream with `_getch()` to **mask the password with asterisks**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PASSWORD_LENGTH 32

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i = 0;
    char password[PASSWORD_LENGTH + 1];
    int ch;
    
    printf("Enter Password (max length: %d): ", PASSWORD_LENGTH);

    while (i < PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
        ch = _getch();
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == 27) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == '\b') {
            if (i > 0) {
                printf("\b \b");
                --i;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\t') {
            break;
        }
        else if (ch == 0 || ch == 224) {
            ch = _getch();
            continue;
        }
        else {
            password[i++] = ch;
            printf("*");
        }
    }
    password[i] = '\0';

    printf("\nPassword: %s", password);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt5eX.png)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can get the same TUI as in your screenshot with `dialog` but here's an attempt at it; I define the colors with a `DIALOGRC` generated on the fly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# DIALOGRC overrides:
IFS='' read -r -d '' dialogrc <<'EOF'
use_shadow = OFF
use_colors = ON
screen_color = (GREEN,BLACK,ON)
dialog_color = screen_color
border_color = screen_color
border2_color = screen_color
inputbox_color = screen_color
button_active_color = screen_color
button_inactive_color = screen_color
button_key_active_color = screen_color
button_key_inactive_color = screen_color
button_label_active_color = screen_color
button_label_inactive_color = screen_color
EOF

input_passwd=$(
    3>&1 >/dev/tty \
    DIALOGRC=<(printf %s "$dialogrc") \
    dialog \
    --output-fd 3 \
    --no-lines \
    --insecure \
    --passwordbox $' Please enter the passphrase to\n protect your key' 8 60
) || exit 1

printf '\ninput_password=%q\n' "$input_passwd"
```

[image]

Please notice the redirection of `dialog`'s stdout to `/dev/tty` and how I capture the result though a different file descriptor; the order in `3>&1 >/dev/tty` is important for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement a TUI database interface to build workflow for permission database. Given that TUI interface will not look as good as GUI, dialog provides very reasonable solution, and can be done in 1-2 hours.

For single password field, use password box as below. It produces output similar to your screenshot.

```
input_pw=$(dialog --strdo--insecure --passwordbox "Enter Password ..." 0 0 )

if [ "$input_pw" = "SeCrEt" ] ; then
   do-something
fi
```

Note that for better looking screen you will most likely want to use the "--form" option, which make it easier to "decorate" the screen, add instructions, control field layout, size of widgets, etc. It took me about 1 day of work to figure it out, and integrate it into my scripts (front end for permission database).